# How to convert String with no time into full date with time using DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, datetimeformatter

Hi I am trying to convert a `String` into date using `DateTimeFormatter`,
such as `"20210628"` to `"Mon Jun 28 00:00:00 UTC 2021"`.
It can be achieved easily using `SimpleDateFormatter` but I want to achieve it using `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What did not work? Can you show some attempt(s), please?

Comment: Start figuring out how to get your `String` to a `LocalDate`, then figure out how to get into a `LocalDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` based on your requirements

Comment: Yes, as deHaar already mentioned, please show your attempt. If you already know how to do it using a `SimpleDateFormatter`, then you are already close.

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMdd", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("20210628", dtfInput);
        OffsetDateTime odt = date.atTime(OffsetTime.of(LocalTime.MIN, ZoneOffset.UTC));
        System.out.println(odt);

        // Custom format
        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss O uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(dtfOutput.format(odt));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-06-28T00:00Z
Mon Jun 28 00:00:00 GMT 2021
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/K8n2Yi)

Alternatively,

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMdd", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("20210628", dtfInput);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));
        System.out.println(zdt);

        // Custom format
        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss O uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(dtfOutput.format(zdt));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-06-28T00:00Z[Etc/UTC]
Mon Jun 28 00:00:00 GMT 2021
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/dlfN1G)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: I had this in mind, too... But OP explicitly asked for the zone id `UTC` in the output `String`. Took me quite some time to find out how that's possible ;-)

Comment: UTC and GMT are the same things.

Comment: Yes, I know, but they are not the same terms... OP could accept a `Z`, too.

Comment: However, your answer adds value here.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach using **`java.time`**, too...

Use a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` to get full control over `String` conversion.

Here's a small example that really prints `UTC` instead of `GMT` or `Z` in the desired output:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example String
    String value = "20210628";
    // define a formatter that parses the example String
    DateTimeFormatter dateParser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMdd");
    // define a formatter that converts to a String as desired
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                    .appendPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss")
                                    .appendLiteral(' ')
                                    .appendZoneRegionId()
                                    .appendLiteral(' ')
                                    .appendPattern("uuuu")
                                    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
    // parse the date and use the formatter in order to get the desired result
    String otherValue = LocalDate.parse(value, dateParser)
                                 // add the start of the day
                                 .atStartOfDay()
                                 // apply the desired zone
                                 .atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))
                                 // and format it 
                                 .format(dtf);
    // finally print the conversion
    System.out.println(value + " ---> " + otherValue);
}
```

The output will be as follows:

```
20210628 ---> Mon Jun 28 00:00:00 UTC 2021
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a LocalDateTime object then you can use the following.

```
String getFormattedDate(LocalDateTime datetime){

DateTimeFormatter formatterPreUTC = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss");
DateTimeFormatter formatterPostUTC = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY");

String textPreUTCPart = datetime.format(formatterPreUTC);
String utc = " UTC ";
String textPostUTCPart = datetime.format(formatterPostUTC);

return textPreUTCPart + utc + textPostUTCPart;
}
```